# Funky LINQ Required

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

The below is a CSV string I am working with.  Its much bigger in reality but this is enough to display a pattern.

**Please note that I have put this CSV on seperate lines just to demonstrate my pattern easily.**

**After a CSV split the number of fields are variable depending on how big the original string is i.e. the string is a variable length which makes the number of indexes variable**

**The letter in the pattern may not always be P, it could be U, O or F**

```
G9999999990001800002777107050,
G9999999990002777107HMNLAQKPRLLHRAQRWJ010,
1,
3,
29,
P,
6.74,
11.23,
07,
U,
5.25,
14.29,
08,
O,
6.89,
16.92,
07,
P,
5,
4,
```

I want to pick up the 5th (29) and 6th (P) elements and then miss 2 elements and then pick the next element (07) and the one after (P) and so on until I get to the end of the string.

In this example I will have
29
P
07
P
08
P
07
P

Is there an easy way to do this, I assume LINQ will offer something

Thanks

Comment: You don't say why you want those elements. I'm guessing the rule is 'all elements that are either `P` or followed by a `P`', but that's only a guess. What happens if the first element is `P` ?

Comment: is that CSV? or is each value on a new line? Note: LINQ is not a magic bullet to solve every problem - if the data is as it appears, then `File.ReadAllLines` or `StreamReader` should help.

Comment: Apologies it is a CSV, I thought putting it on a new line might demonstrate my example better. I can change it back to CSV if you prefer

Comment: @Jon: thanks for that, good choice; however, a comment would have been in order to make it obvious. Will you edit the question accordingly?

Comment: Question updated with bold font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full demo on **http://ideone.com/EDof0**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> SpecialIndexes()
    {
        int i=4; 

        while (i<Int32.MaxValue)
        {
            yield return i++;
            yield return i++;
            i += 2;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csvString = "G9999999990001800002777107050,G9999999990002777107HMNLAQKPRLLHRAQRWJ010,1,3,29,P,6.74,11.23,07,P,5.25,14.29,08,P,6.89,16.92,07,P,5,4,";

        var fields = csvString.Split(',');
        var selected = SpecialIndexes()
            .TakeWhile(i => i<fields.Length)
            .Select(i => fields[i]);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", selected.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
29 P 07 P 08 P 07 P
```

---

Comment: I'm getting pretty certain I must have been hell-banned. None of my answers are getting any attention lately :(

Comment: to be fair, I really don't like that static 100 for the range. I might have gone with `Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue - 1).SelectMany(...).TakeWhile(i => i is not outside string length)`

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: I'm pretty positive you haven't tried that

Comment: I've used something like it in the past.

Comment: Could you not do the csvString split first and then the Enumberable.Range becomes Enumerable.Range(1,fields.length)

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich, @Jon There, it's fixed now. Not using clumsy `SelectMany` anymore. This is better all around

Comment: @Jon: yeah, it's exactly what happens already (the indexes enumerable is deferred, or _lazy_). Anyways, it was my braindamage of typing `Where` instead of `TakeWhile` there. Sry

Comment: But surely creating an enmerable all the way to the max in value is more work? Surely just using the fields.length is good enough?

Comment: @Jon it doesn't actually do that. Check out Jon Skeet's book which does a great explanation of how LINQ and IEnumerable actually work.

Comment: @Jon: read up on deferred or lazy enumeration http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+deferred+ienumerable

Answer (score 4):

```
line.Split(',')  //split on commas as it seems from your question that's your input
    .Skip(2) //skip the first two entries
    .Where((l, i) => i % 4 == 3 || i % 4 == 0) //take every 3rd and 4th item
    .Skip(1); //skip the first item since the index is divisible by 4
```

But this doesn't at all seem descriptive of what the code is doing, I'd at least put a comment.

Comment: Can you please comment it for my unworthy eyes because I dont get it!

Comment: it's not actually about lines... the OP has clarified

Answer (score 0):

i've done something like this yesterday... here's my code

```
//Create a new variable of string
var x = string.Empty;
//Open a new FileStream
using (var fs = new FileStream(path,...))
//Open the StreamReader
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
//Read out the whole CSV
   x = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

//Split up the string by ',' and whitespaces. dismiss empty entries
var stringArray = x.Split(new char[] { ',', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

//stolen code following 
var myEnumerable = stringArray.Skip(2)
                              .Where((item, index) => index % 4 == 3 || index % 4 == 0)
                              .Skip(1);
```

Comment: This is similar to Yuriy's answer. Can you explain whats going on. I dont quite understand the mod stuff and not to complain but that isnt working on my CSV

Comment: explained it... sry i have wrote ';' in the split instead of ',' because in my program is used ';' :p sorry for that... hoping for an up ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] thestrings = source.Split(',');
string lastItem = thestrings.FirstOrDefault();
List<string> keepers = new List<string>();

foreach(string item in thestrings)
{
  if (item == "P")
  {
    if (lastItem != "P")
    {
      keepers.Add(lastItem);
    }
    keepers.Add(item);
  }
  lastItem = item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse a row I would use a RegEx instead Linq as it is compiled and much faster.